# Git-LFS: Refs not found so failed to push?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am attempting to set up git LFS on a repository that is not a brand new repository. As such, I have had to convert it to lfs.

Everything was going ok, I performed the conversion, did all the necessary garbage collection, resolved all the conflicts as a result of merging, all that's left is to push.

Upon attempting a push, it gets about halfway through all the files it needs to track, then fails, giving me the message:

```
Trying to push "<File path to lfs-tracked image file>.jpg" 
with OID 4be1fb289502b3e5ccc0c9b8b01c31f73670bb2e273570358361fc8c98592571.
Not found in <File path to repository>/.git/lfs/objects/4b/e1.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:<company>/<name of repository>.git'
```

Looking in the objects folder, it seems that most of them have a file with some kind of ID in that long format, but "4b/e1" is empty. I'm assuming the reference was lost somewhere during garbage collection.

My question is: Is there anything I can do about this to potentially fix it, either by recovering the reference or getting it to create a new one, or am I a but sunk regarding this repository? This is the only thing preventing me from completing the LFS setup, so I'm hoping I can find a solution.

Comment: So am I to understand that nobody on Stack Overflow is using Git-LFS, then? Is there no way to recover / generate references? I'm looking online, but not much luck. So far I've had to add images in manually. It worked for a bit, but it seems it's more than just the one batch of images, so I have no idea how long it would take me to go through all of it.

Comment: Hard to help you without some details as to how you performed the conversion leading to the missing `.git/lfs/objects` files. Adding the files manually would work, but addressing the root problem would probably be more efficient if you have a lot of these files.

Comment: It's no longer an issue. I was able to add the missing files manually and complete the push. Issue was caused because I was using SSH over HTTPS, which apparently Git LFS can have problems with sometimes.

Comment: I'm running into similar issue, how did you resolve it ?